Heroku cli login error: unable to verify the first certificate
I treid to login using following commands to setup new heroku project. But I'm getting the error
**unable to verify the first certificate**
heroku auth:login --browser=chrome
heroku: Press any key to open up the browser to login or q to exit:
Error: unable to verify the first certificate

I tried to update heroku, but same issue
heroku update
heroku: Updating CLI... !
Error: unable to verify the first certificate

Even any other heorku commands it's returning same error.
Any ideas to fix it?
I treid to check if there is any HTTP proxy blocking the request, but I don't a proxy setup in my machine. I have searched other stack questions none seem to have an answer for this when using heroku logging in.
